# looking for jquery modal windows

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

i need windows-like theme module windows using jquery or javascript. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Comment: how to onable dragging of window?

Comment: To disable the draggable behaviour:  $( ".selector" ).dialog({ draggable: false });

Answer (score 1):

Use [modal dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) from [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).

If you don't want to use them for some example, use the [blockUI plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) to make whatever you want modal.

Answer (score 0):

You can make yourself a simple jquery modal window without the use of jquery ui or bootstrap. Here is a very helpful tutorial: http://www.devilogs.com/responsive-modal-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of big plugins with many options, themes, and the like. I've just started working with this minimalist plugin, which looks quite good: https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal